# Can`t publish a MVC project to Azure

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, azure

I am deploying the first time a **MVC5** project to **Azure**. I went for the **codefirst approach** with an existing database that I had on my **SSMS**. Then I migrated the database with the **SQLAzureMW** tool to a Azure database. It works great with the connectionString pointing to the Azure database when I am debugging locally from within `VS2013`.

But when I am publishing my project from VS to Azure, and try to login or access anything that has database access, it brings the follwing error(The site works fine):

```
Error. An error occurred while processing your request.
```

I tried various attempt but unfortunately without success. Any hint what this error might cause? Or a workaround to get the project online?

**Update / Solution:**

I copied the connectionString from the web.config that points to the Azure database into the fields of the settings section of the publish wizard of VS.

Comment: Make sure the Web.config that matches the solution configuration has the connection string for your Azure database.

Answer (score 2):

Check this comprehensive article about troubleshooting issues in Azure:

> During development and testing of a web application, you can
>   troubleshoot by running in debug mode or by using IntelliTrace. You
>   can run in debug mode locally in IIS Express or remotely in a Windows
>   Azure Web Site. But for errors that occur only in production, the best
>   way to debug might be by reviewing logs that application code or the
>   web server creates. This tutorial shows how to use Visual Studio tools
>   that help debug an application while it runs in a Windows Azure Web
>   Site, by running in debug mode remotely or by viewing application and
>   web server logs.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/

Also, make sure that your Azure SQL database has a port open in firewall to allow traffic from within Azure:

> When an application from Windows Azure attempts to connect to your SQL
>   Database server, the SQL Database firewall looks for a specific
>   firewall setting that indicates whether Windows Azure connections are
>   allowed. A firewall setting with starting and ending address equal to
>   0.0.0.0 indicates that Windows Azure connections are allowed. If the connection attempt is not allowed, the request does not reach the SQL
>   Database server.

Comment: Thank you, it looks amazing, I will consider that article for future trouble shooting!